# How to authenticate new users using only social media auth but also only by Admin user invitation?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-allauth, django-socialauth

My web app currently uses `django-allauth` to authenticate users via sign-up. What I want to achieve is that sign-up is disabled except for the situation where current **Admin** users send an invitation (via email) to someone asking them to sign-up, and then the sign-up/registration take place using only a **third party** source (i.e. social media authentication), such as Office 365, Facebook, LinkedIn etc.

As part of this authentication pipeline, I would like the Admin user who is inviting to be able to select which social media/third parties the user is allowed to authenticate with.

As I have said, I currently use [`django-allauth`](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) to authenticate using Django. I know [`django-invitations`](https://github.com/bee-keeper/django-invitations) allows users to invite other users to join, but I not sure if it can be restricted to Admin users only or to just third party auth, or let me select third party auths.

In my settings.py I have:

```
ACCOUNT_OPEN_SIGNUP = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'optional'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_APPROVAL_REQUIRED = True
```

with an invitation template etc. which lets me invite users.